# How to prevent table cell border to be cut by cell image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have a table view and i want to add image on it by using the following code,

first by overriding `layoutSubviews`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(15, 5, 50, 45);
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}
```

and then using it in the `-(MyTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
 NSString *imageUrlString = [userInfoResponse[indexPath.row - beginIndex] objectForKey:@"image_url"];
        NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
        if ( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:imageUrlString] == nil ) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL] forKey:imageUrlString];
        }
        UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:imageUrlString]];
        cell.imageView.image = img;
}
```

and in this line i added

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 55.0;
}
```

it works fine with this little problem (see attached image). I don't want the cell border line to be interrupted by the image.

[image]

I tried playing on codes but it wont help. Anyone knows the answer? please help. Thanks

NOTE: It works well with iOS 6, this screenshot is on iOS 7. Can it be a new settings for iOS 7 `UITableView`?

Comment: It seems that your image is taller than the cell. Try increasing the height of the table rows.

Comment: @tarmes, i added my row height value for you to see that my image is smaller than the row height

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to your table view controller and put these codes into viewDidLoad:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) //should check version to prevent force closed
{
    self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to adjust the height of your `UITableViewCell` then inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` use:

```
[cell clipsToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answer above fully extend the border the entire length of the screen. The only way to achieve this is by pasting the code below in your ViewController:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
  }

  if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
  }
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
  }

  if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table view cell is too small. Implement this method in your controller and adjust height for the cell.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad put:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: Why?  A little explanation makes a better answer.